How to achieve automatic nesting of pattern application
I want to apply the following rules:
rule1 = {d[i_][t[a_, b_, c_]] -> t[d[i][a], d[i][b], d[i][c]]}
rule2 = {d[i_][d[j_][x_]] -> If[i < j, d[j - 1][d[i][x]], d[i][d[j][x]]]}

When I apply them consequently in any order, I get the desired result:
(d[0][d[1][t[a, b, c]]] //. rule1) //. rule2
(*t[d[0][d[0][a]], d[0][d[0][b]], d[0][d[0][c]]]*)

(d[0][d[1][t[a, b, c]]] //. rule2) //. rule1
(*t[d[0][d[0][a]], d[0][d[0][b]], d[0][d[0][c]]]*)

However applying them both as a set I don't:
d[0][d[1][t[a, b, c]]] //. (rule1 \[Union] rule2)
(*d[0][d[0][t[a, b, c]]]*)

Why, and how to avoid consequent application? I want to have a single set of rules.

If time order of application matters, use
  Fold[(#1//.#2&),  expr,  {  {a:>b},...}.  Sometimes its useful to evaluate simplified by Fold[(Simplify[#1//.#2]& ) .It's often crucial to control the patterns generated and used after simplification.


rule1 = {d[i_][t[a_, b_, c_]] -> t[d[i][a], d[i][b], d[i][c]]};

rule2 = {d[i_][d[j_][x_]] -> If[i < j, d[j - 1][d[i][x]], d[i][d[j][x]]]};

expr = d[0][d[1][t[a, b, c]]];


In addition to Fold, as @Roland F points out, you can proceed programmatically:
ApplyNestedRules[expr_, rules : {__Rule} | {__RuleDelayed}] := 
Module[{result = expr},
Do[result = result //. rules[[iter]], {iter, Length@rules}];
result]

ApplyNestedRules[expr, rule1 \[Union] rule2]


t[d[0][d[0][a]], d[0][d[0][b]], d[0][d[0][c]]]

